# HttpClient error calling webapi from another webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, openid-connect

[image]I have two webapi developed in asp.net core 2.0 and is secured with identityserver4 framework. Both the apis are ssl enabled

I am accessing the webapi using angular2 application.

Everything works fine when i access the webapi individually from the angular application. But when i try to access the another webapi from one webapi, i am getting

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A security error occurred
```

Below is the code i am using in one of the webapi:

```
       var request = CurrentContext.Request;
        var authHeader = request.Headers["Authorization"];
        var authHeaderVal = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);

        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://localhost:5001/")
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeaderVal;


        var response = await client.GetAsync("api/alerts/1");
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {

        }
```

Comment: Your issue isn't realted to Angular there, since the error comes from your back-end. I'm removing the Angular tag from your question. Also, if you provide the full error trace, this would be easier, because this seems like a very generic error you have there.

Comment: only thing that can be different in the two requests is the auth header you are passing it. set a break point and confirm it is correct. Also, HttpClient should be static. HttpClient acts similar to a browser. You are effectively opening a new window every request even though you can make multiple requests in the same window.

Answer (score 1):

It seams like a **CORS** issue.

**CORS** stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.
As the name implies you trying to access resources from a different origin, it could be a different domain, protocol or port.

**CORS** Requests are enforced by your browser on servers that don't have **CORS** enabled, check [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors) on how to enable **CORS** on your api.

The **CORS** rule is not mandatory to be enforced but most browsers enforce it for security issues, hence some developer tools such as PostMan ignore it to make development easier.

Another solution would be to install a plugin to browser that disables the restriction such as [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) if you're using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are failing SSL verification since you are running on localhost. You can override verification. Also, HttpClient should be static so you should update the code accordingly.

```
var request = CurrentContext.Request;
var authHeader = request.Headers["Authorization"];
var authHeaderVal = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);

using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (msg, cert, chain, err) => { return true; };
    using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://localhost:5001/")
        })
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeaderVal;


        var response = await client.GetAsync("api/alerts/1");
        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```